# Why does TypeScript assume that the document object is always available?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have the following line of code in a function:

```
if (!document) return;
```

For some reason, I am getting the following ESLint error from the official TypeScript rules:

> Unnecessary conditional, value is always
> falsy. eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition)

It is not true that `document` is always truthy. When the code runs on the server, in a Node.js program or as part of a react server component, the `document` object is not available.

Is there a way to get TypeScript to understand that `document` may be `undefined`?

**EDIT:**

I intend for the code to be able to run in *both* a node.js (server) environment, and a browser environment. Therefore, `env` in eslint config is set to `{ node: true, browser: true, }` and `lib.dom.d.ts` is included via this tsconfig: `"lib": ["ESNext", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],`

Comment: • Is this an ESLint question? If not, could you [edit] to write a [mre] that doesn't rely on it? (e.g., "why does `document.getRootNode()` not complain?" or something) • Does your project include `lib.dom.d.ts` in its lib? If so then you've told it that the DOM is available and `document` is defined, and you should remove it (in which case `document` won't even be recognized as existing as a variable).  Could you [edit] to clarify whether or not you intend to include the DOM in your dependencies?

Comment: @jcalz I guess it is partially an ESLint question, but it an official TS rule that is complaining. In other words, TypeScript itself believes the type is `Document`, and not `Document | undefined`, which is what I expected. When `env` in ESLint config is both `node` and `browser`, it should understand that the code could run in either environment...

Comment: @jcalz I tried module augmentation to overwrite `document` from `lib.dom.d.ts`, as shown in the docs below, but TS wouldn't allow me to redeclare `document` value. Is there a way around that, i.e. to make TS understand that `document` *could* be `undefined` (i.e. that the code is expected to run in both a node.js environment and a browser environment). https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation

Comment: I'm not sure how TypeScript would know or care what your eslint env is set as, but I don't know eslint. Does eslint decide whether or not to include `lib.dom.d.ts` or is it your tsconfig? If it's included then `document` exists (according to TS) and if it's not then it doesn't.  I don't know of any hybrid configuration that includes things conditionally; you might be interested in [ms/TS#53971](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53971). Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: (see prev comment) No, you can't re-define a `declare var` which is what `document` is.

Comment: @jcalz Indeed, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53971 does cover the same use case I am facing. Also, I think you are right regarding `env`, it is probably irrelevant here, since we have `lib.dom.d.ts`. There is no way to overwrite the `document` type, from `lib.dom.d.ts`? It is a bit odd that there is no support for code that can run in both environments, where checks on `window` and `document` is necessary.

Comment: I see you've accepted the answer that pointed out that accessing a nonexistent variable is a runtime error; I'd think you'd change the question to add something like `globalThis.document ||= undefined` at the top to avoid this situation, but that's your prerogative.

Comment: @jcalz I accepted it because it did remove the ESLint error. I am not sure why it works (added a comment below yours on the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [global `document` variable is declared in `lib.dom.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/60cf79127af5025ebdd239aa47ca136e7a366347/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L27375) as a `Document` and not a `Document | undefined` or anything else.

Right now you have two choices: include it and accept that `document` is a `Document`, or don't include it and then `document` is not known to be a variable at all.  There is at present no facility in TypeScript to "conditionally" include a library, so the use case of having a runtime way of discovering whether the DOM exists is not supported.

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#53971](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53971) asking for some better support for such multi-environment code, but it has very little engagement and so I wouldn't expect to see it implemented anytime soon.

So right now the only way to do what you're asking is not to include `lib.dom.d.ts`, but instead include or declare your own version of it where `document` is of type `Document | undefined` (but you'd have to take care to access it as `globalThis.document` instead of just `document` because dereferencing a missing variable results in [a `ReferenceError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) and not `undefined` (or if you want to use `document` without worrying, you can write `globalThis.document ||= undefined` at the top of your code, so that `document` is definitely a global variable no matter what).

This would be a large undertaking and it's not clear you'd benefit much.  For the sake of expedience I'd recommend you just use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or suppress that lint rule for that one line or some other workaround that doesn't actually protect you a possibly-absent DOM, but at least doesn't give you errors in your environment.

Comment: It seems indeed that your answer addresses the underlying question here. I tried to add `globalThis.document ||= undefined`, but that causes a bigger issue: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Document'. I guess I have to omit `lib.dom.d.ts` for that to work? If so, assertion is probably the only viable solution here, as you say, since the code does run in the browser (and in node.js).

Comment: Assuming you don't want to fork the dom lib, you can use type assertions to do whatever (`globalThis.document ||= undefined!` will probably work).  This is essentially all written in my answer; not sure if that wasn't properly conveyed.

Comment: Type assertions here just dig a deeper grave of errors. Assuming we wrote `globalThis.document ||= undefined!` you get the following error on the LHS: `Unnecessary conditional, value is always truthy.`, and the following on the RHS: `Forbidden non-null assertion.`. Again, these are eslint errors, but from the TypeScript team. We essentially end up replacing one error for two.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this two methods : inform TypeScript that document may potentially be undefined by using a type assertion or type guard.

You can use a type assertion (as) to tell TypeScript that document may be undefined:
typescript

```
if (!(document as Document | undefined)) return;
```

You can use a type guard to check if document is defined:

```
if (typeof document === 'undefined') return;
```

Using one of these methods, TypeScript will understand that document might be undefined, and the ESLint error should disappear.

Comment: Thanks. I get the first approach, but wonder why the second (type guard) approach works. It should still complain, since it apparently knows (incorrectly) that document always has type `Document`. I have `env: { node: true, browser: true, }` in the eslint config, thus it should define document as `Document | undefined`, not just `Document`...

Comment: What about adding this: `declare let document: Document | undefined`, would that overwrite the type from `lib.dom.d.ts`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get TypeScript to understand that `document` may be `undefined`?

This is the wrong question to ask. When running under Node.js, `document` is not `undefined`! Rather, `document` *doesn't exist*, and the statement `if (!document) return;` will throw `ReferenceError: document is not defined`. You need to use a `typeof` check instead:

```
if (typeof document === 'undefined') return;
```

You do *not* want to tell TypeScript that `document` has the type `Document | undefined` (meaning that the `document` variable exists but may have the value `undefined`). This type would allow the erroneous code `if (!document) return;` to compile successfully, only to crash at run time.

I'm not aware of a TypeScript language feature where you can declare that a global variable *conditionally* exists and thus requires `typeof` checks.

Comment: Thank you, helpful context. I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: Presumably one would use `globalThis.document` instead of `document` to avoid the reference error, or write `globalThis.document ||= undefined` before the check

Comment: @jcalz: True. I thought the main goal here is to avoid the ESLint error, and I'd be curious to know whether `if (!globalThis.document)` still triggers the error.

Comment: @jcalz and Michael: Just changing it to `if (!globalThis.document) return` does *not* remove the error (i.e. `globalThis.document` is still of type `Document` and therefore always truthy). Writing `if (typeof document === 'undefined') return;` *does* remove the errror, but I do not understand why. If TS knows `document` is of type `Document`, and thus always truthy, then it should also know that `typeof document` is never `"undefined"`.

Comment: I think this is a question for the ESLint developers (TypeScript itself doesn't care). Perhaps they just haven't bothered to add a rule that checks usages of `typeof`. Of course, here the absence of an ESLint error when using `typeof` is convenient, right?

Comment: Indeed it is. Really appreciate the suggestion, though I guess it does not address the underlying problem. Yes, it might be that they just forgot to check that syntax in the eslint rule (it is an official TS rule).

Comment: On the other hand, maybe ESLInt doesn't report an error for `typeof` because that's the idiomatic way to check for the existence of a variable in situations like this...

Comment: Heh, good point, that might actually be true....

Answer (score 0):

The problem likely comes from your ESLint config. You need to specify the `env` option in your `.eslintrc` file accordingly, [like so](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#specifying-environments).

Comment: You are right, I have `env: { node: true, browser: true, }` in the eslint config. It is a bit surprising that ESLint / TS assumes that the code always runs in the browser though. It should define document as `Document | undefined`, not just `Document`...